# Can't use special characters in listchars even if setting scriptencoding to utf-8

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, encoding, listchars

Here is my `.vimrc` file:

```
set encoding=utf-8
scriptencoding utf-8
set list
set listchars=tab:→·
```

When I open vim, it will show an error message `E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:→·`

My vim is `Vi IMproved 8.1 Huge version without GUI` and the `multi_lang` feature is enabled. I don't know why it doesn't support special characters `→·`.

---

*Edit*

Thanks Christian Brabandt for pointing my error that `tab` need two characters. However, when I set `tab` to `→·`, it still didn't work. And finally, I find that this problem is caused by XShell because this configuration works well under GNOME. After changing the XShell Terminal Type to `linux` or `ansi` instead of `xterm`, it works! But if I change it back, it still works. I don't know why. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: the `tab` suboption of the listchars settings needs **two** characters!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks, but it still didn't work. The question has been updated.

Comment: what's the output of `locale`?